# Как создавать новую страницу, аккаунт, топик в php?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, веб-программирование

Всем доброго времени суток! Знаю, знаю, вопрос задан очень неккоректно, но сейчас я попытаюсь быстренько объяснить, что меня интересует. Учу php, стараюсь сам находить источники и решать свои проблемы, но в этот раз что-то завис.
Суть:
Как осуществляется добавление нового топика на вебсайт, чтоб id отображался в браузере, по типу mysite.com/topics/245646
Например, здесь вот адрес юзера:
https://geekbrains.ru/users/2234673
Здесь таким же образом адрес и id фильма.
https://www.kinopoisk.ru/film/726753/

Поскажите куда смотреть, а еще лучше, если есть ссылочки на туториалы (можно на английском)! Спасибо всем большое!

Comment: Почитайте про ЧПУ

Comment: Это стандартный роутинг для сайтов где сделан доступ к объекту по его идентификатору - object/id - https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можете использовать одну из библиотек для роутинга, например klein php

Код выглядит примерно так

```
$klein = new \Klein\Klein();
$klein->respond('GET', '/topic/[i:id]', function ($request) {
  return "Вы указали id = " . $request->param('id');
});    
$klein->dispatch();
```

Так-же необходимо настроить ваш веб сервер так, чтобы он перенаправлял все запросы на несуществующие ресурсы на ваш скрипт (например index.php) в котором и будут обрабатываться запросы с вышеприведенным кодом